# Heroku returning can't mass assign?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, console

I planned everything carefully and tested locally, but after deploying may have created many useless records that have crashed the app on heroku.

My aim is to consolidate many models into one Topic model, so I used the below script in Heroku console (though should have tested one record at first):

```
> Question.find_each do |q|
* @qt=q.title
> @qd=q.description
> @q="Question"
> @ca=q.created_at
> @ui=q.user.id
> @uvt=q.user_votes_total
> Topic.create!({:title => @qt, :description => [@qd], :kind => @q, :created_at=>@ca, :user_id=>@ui, :user_votes_total=>@uvt })
> end
```

Heroku returns this:

```
Question Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE ("questions"."id" >= 0) ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1000
User Load (6.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3331 ORDER BY users.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

And, this DOH!:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: title, description, kind, created_at, user_id, user_votes_total
```

My topic model looks like this:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :kind, :user_id, :tag_list,
              :subject, :image_attributes, :tags_attributes, :created_at,
              :user_votes_total
  validates :title, :presence => true,
                :length => { :minimum => 5 }
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :kind, :presence => true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :adds
  default_scope order: 'topics.created_at DESC'

  votable_by :users
  acts_as_taggable

  has_one :image, :as => :parent, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :image, :allow_destroy => true
    after_create do
     self.create_image unless image
    end
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable, :dependent => :destroy

  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search, against: [:title, :description, :kind],
     using: {tsearch: {dictionary: "english"}}
end
```

I have searched for relevant information, but can't figure out why Heroku is not playing along. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Comment: apologies if this is basic (but believe me this has been done in the past) have you run  heroku run rake db:migrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome the issue by running:

```
`heroku restart`
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ps